# Why the energy of light in a photonic structure ≠ the energy of its equivalent circuit model generated by EIFE?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, computational-physics

For simplicity, we suppose $\epsilon_0=\mu_0=1$ and that the photonic structure is only made of perfect metal and vacuum.

The electric field and the current density are related by the Green's function, writtern as $E=GJ$, so the energy of light is

\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{E}=\int dV(\frac{1}{2}|E|^2+\frac{1}{2}|H|^2)=\int dV |E|^2=J^\dagger (G^\dagger G) J
\end{equation}

---

Using Electric Field Integral Equation (EFIE, a method of moment in numerical electromagnetics), we start with the boundary condition $J^\dagger E=0$, sustituting $E=GJ$, and finally have
\begin{equation}
    G=\frac{1}{i\omega}\nabla C^{-1}\nabla^\dagger+i\omega L
\end{equation}
Based on the circuit theory, the energy is $\mathcal{E}=\frac{1}{2}q^\dagger C^{-1} q+\frac{1}{2}J^\dagger L J$, which can be simplied as $\mathcal{E}=J^\dagger (\frac{1}{2i\omega}G) J$.

---

Obviously, there is no evidence to show $J^\dagger (G^\dagger G) J = J^\dagger (\frac{1}{2i\omega}G) J$. But is it satisfied? If not, what is the difference between two definitions of energy?